# running scripts that have sudo in it as sudo at startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup-scripts

I have a script that I want to run on startup.  This script launches vms using sudo VBoxManage.

How can I a) Execute this vm start script on the computer startup and b) make sure the sudos don't need me to actually type in a password.

I figured rc.local somehow but not sure how to handle the fact that it requires sudo to run VBoxManage with

Comment: You don't need to use sudo in an old-style startup script, because they already run as root.

Comment: Okay, so I just somehow add them to the rc.local file and it will run as root?

Comment: Actually I think that worked, but alas the virtual box vdis are on a separate harddrive that isn't ready right away when the machine first boots :( so it fails I think.  (dont know why it takes that drive so long to automount)